# Cosa significa "sgrossata" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Meglio morti* di Marcello Fois ho letto:

> «Una bambina che ha imparato quello che bisogna fare: dare una mano per la *sgrossata* del sabato pomeriggio, passare il panno umido per far risplendere il lavello della cucina,  strizzare lo straccio per l'ultimo risciacquo sui pavimenti,  prima della cera.»

Ho cercato la parola [sgrossata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sgrossata/) nel dizionario e ho trovato:

> **sgrossata** s. f. [der. di sgrossare]. – Atto, operazione di sbozzare, di cominciare a lavorare qualcosa: *dare una s. a qualcosa*.

Non riesco a capire però il senso di questo vocabolo nella frase citata. Si riferisce a qualche lavoro domestico che si fa di sabato pomeriggio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direi che si riferisca semplicemente alle pulizie della casa: si parte dal “grosso” (spazzare per terra, buttare i rifiuti...) e in un secondo momento si passa a lavare e lucidare.

Comment: DaG, noto che ti intendi bene anche di pulizie :)

Answer (score 5):

Come riferisce la definizione, per sgrossata si intende in genere il "fare il grosso del lavoro" a cui poi possono seguire delle fasi di rifinitura.

Per rimanere nel campo dell'esempio riportato, si può dire "dare una sgrossata ai pavimenti" intendendo una pulizia (e. g. passare lo straccio) che tolga il grosso dello sporco.

Tuttavia nell'esempio credo che per sgrossata si intenda "grosso lavoro" (di pulizia, in questo caso) poiché viene riferito ad uno specifico momento temporale dedicato completamente alle pulizie (sabato pomeriggio) e poiché si indicano anche lavori di rifinitura (e.g. passare la cera).